# Precaution after receiving forged request

Tags: security

Today I noticed this error in our log:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/app_path/testp3_pospr_waw_pl/some_file.php'
>   (include_path='.:...') in
>   /var/www/path/to/script.php on line 36" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: offending.ip.address.33, server:
>   api.example.com, request: "GET http:// testp3.pospr.waw.pl/testproxy.php
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "testp3.pospr.waw.pl"

As I understand it, it means a GET request ended up on our server which is *not* `testp3.pospr.waw.pl`. So, someone has set that domain to (locally) resolve to our IP (I'm not sure why).

That domain [is listed as a threat](https://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/domain/default.aspx?domain=testp3.pospr.waw.pl). I have since patched the code that tried to `require` the script on our server. But, is that it? Should I take extra steps?

**Update**

As per @TeroKilkanen's comment, I'm adding the config file. Nothing fancy as you'd see:

Main site:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/www/path/to/error.log;
    root /var/www/path/to/app;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

API:

```
server {
        listen our.ip.goes.here;
        server_name api.example.com;
        access_log off;
        error_log /var/www/path/to/error.log;
        rewrite_log on;
        root /var/www/path/to/app/api;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                rewrite "/(.*)" /server.php?path=$1 break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Unless your server is configured in somehow odd way, this shouldn't be the reason. Show your website configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have added the config file. Could you elaborate please? What *shouldn't be the reason*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a virtualhost with `default_server` option that returns 404 to all visits.

Now, what happens is that when your IP address receives a HTTP requests where the HTTP Host -header contains `testp3.pospr.waw.pl`, nginx selects the first virtual host in your configuration to process the request.

When you configure a `default_server`, nginx sends all requests to unknown virtual hosts to that `server` block.

Then again, something in your software is using the value of `Host` header as a directory path, which can be dangerous. You should fix that issue too.

Comment: You are right, the host is used as the beginning of data path. That way, we have the app in a single directory and adding *sites* or *instances* only requires adding data directories and virtual host configs. I have patched the code to first check if the path exists before attempting to include the (site config) file. The `default_server` method is an excellent solution too. Thanks.